# Calculate $ \int_0^\infty \exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^2)x^k \, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration

$k \in \mathbb N$.
I know, that this is an odd function, if $k$ is an even number. So I have to calculate the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and that would be $0$ for $k$ as an even number. But how do I calculate the integral for an odd number of $k$. Wolfram Alpha says something like:

$$\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)x^k \, \mathrm{d}x = 2^{\frac{k-1}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)$$

But how do I get there? Or is there a easier method?

Comment: Sub $x=\sqrt{2 u}$ and use the definition of the Gamma function.

Comment: Compute $\int e^{-ax^2/2}=\sqrt{\pi/a}$ by squaring and converting to polar coordinates. Then take the derivative of the answer with respect to $a$ $k/2$ times and set $a=1$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $t=\dfrac{x^2}2,~$ and then employ the well-known integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).